# Mobile Accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am building a mobile application and in a page I have few labels to be updated on button click. as per the business requirements I need to read about the updated labels to the user in order. How do I do it

At present, I am setting the label with a slight delay so that each message will get picked up be the reader. But that's not helping me when the text is big. Is there anyway, I can set the order for the updated labels and get it picked up in order?

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

In order to modifiy different HTML element and make the screenreader announce them in the order they have been modified without interrupting the previous element, you can use the `aria-live=polite` attribute on each tag.

> When regions are specified as polite, assistive technologies will notify users of updates but generally do not interrupt the current task, and updates take low priority.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the tabindex attribute?

[See details on this link to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

Comment: Do not use `tabindex` with a value greater than 0. -1 and 0 have their use, but a positive value is an awful idea. W3Schools is also not a good resource for anything related to accessibility.